# VSIX Installer crashes if FIPS encryption is enabled

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vsix

Is there a work around for the VSIX Installer if the FIPS encryption is enabled.

Error details:
Application: vsixinstaller.exe

Framework Version: v4.0.30319

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException

at System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider..ctor()

Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)

at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(System.String, System.Object[])

at System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create()

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Shared.TelemetryLogger.EndBlockingProcessTelemetry(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.TelemetryScope`1<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.OperationEvent>, Boolean, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)

at VSIXInstaller.BlockPage.NavigateToInstall(System.Threading.CancellationToken)

Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])

at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(System.Object[])

at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)

at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)

at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()

at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)

at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)

at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)

at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)

at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)

at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()

at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()

at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)

at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)

at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)

at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)

at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)

at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)

at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)

at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)

at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)

at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)

at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)

at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)

at VSIXInstaller.App.Main()

Comment: What is the callstack? The VSIX installer is a managed application, you can attach a debugger to it without too much trouble.

Comment: I have added the error in event viewer on crash.

Answer (score 0):

Well, decompiling the `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` constructor shows the following:

```
public MD5CryptoServiceProvider() {
    if (CryptoConfig.AllowOnlyFipsAlgorithms)
        throw new InvalidOperationException(Environment.GetResourceString("Cryptography_NonCompliantFIPSAlgorithm"));
    // ...
}
```

So, basically, the .NET framework is explicitly checking for FIPS compliance and throwing an exception when it's enabled, which the VSIX installer doesn't handle.

I suggest opening a bug with Microsoft Connect (including the stack trace), since the installer should likely be able to handle this exception and continue with the installation regardless.

You might have luck working around this locally to enable an install by modifying the VSIX installer executable's configuration file to [forcibly disable FIPS compliance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/enforcefipspolicy-element).

Comment: I tried modifying the configuration file but it is still the same error. I will just open a bug.

Comment: Added a bug in Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3142760/vsix-installer-crashes-if-the-fips-encrytion-is-enabled-on-the-system